# Stuck for months with data file reading, now getting NaN error when processing the data in VB

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have been working on this VB project for over a month and am still stuck. I need to read a series of numbers from a data file then average them. There are 0's separating the series so I have 2 if statements to sort it, but I keep getting this NaN error.

```
Dim sum As Integer
    Dim count As Integer
    Dim TotalSum As Integer
    Dim TotalCount As Integer
    Dim Average As Double
    Dim TotalAverage As Double
    Dim seriescount As Double
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim intarray(i) As Double
    Dim srRead As IO.StreamReader = New IO.StreamReader("NumberData.txt")


    i = srRead.ReadLine()


     Do While i < count
             If intarray(i) <> 0 Then
            sum += intarray(i)
            seriescount += 1
        Else
            Average = sum / seriescount
            lstNumbers.Items.Add(Average)
            sum = 0
            seriescount = 0
            TotalSum += Average
            TotalCount += 1
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Loop
    TotalAverage = TotalSum / TotalCount
    lstNumbers.Items.Add(TotalAverage)
```

please help

Comment: Try change [srRead.ReadLine()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.io.streamreader.readline) to [srRead.Read()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ath1fht8(v=vs.110).aspx). Also, turn [Option Explicit and Option Strict](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311329)  `On`.

Comment: can you post an example of the data in the text file? this will help us to help you.

Comment: here is a sample of my data. 10
15
20
20
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
0
10
20
30
40
50
60
0

Answer (score 0):

Your code contains several errors. You store your data into a single integer, then use that integer like if it was a index. I fixed what i could, but I suggest you start using the strict mode on future projects until you understand how type conversion Works.

This should work or at the very least give you a clear idea of what is wrong in your code

```
Dim sum, count, TotalSum, TotalCount As Integer
Dim Average, TotalAverage , seriescount as double
Dim srRead As IO.StreamReader = New IO.StreamReader("NumberData.txt")
dim content as string = srRead.ReadLine()

for i as integer = 0 to content.lenght-1
    If content.chars(i) <> "0" Then
        sum += content.chars(i) //cint needed if you use strict
        seriescount += 1
    Else
        TotalSum += sum
        TotalCount += seriescount
        Average = sum / seriescount
        lstNumbers.Items.Add(Average)
        sum = 0
        seriescount = 0
    End If
Loop
TotalAverage = TotalSum / TotalCount
lstNumbers.Items.Add(TotalAverage)
```

Comment: I tried that but I still don't get whats wrong with it. I'm terrible at programming.